# Internally resolving HTML of specified URL using routing

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am developing a web application using Play Framework 2.3.9 with Java. I would love to have some method that gets the corresponding Result for a specified Call or URL. I know that this is basically routing, but I would like to be able to call this method from my Controller, so I can for example retrieve the HTML for several pages at once. I need this for widget support in my application.

Example input: routes.ApplicationController.index("Hello world")

Example output: the corresponding Result with HTML body

Is there any such method in Play? Or does anyone have his own solution for this? I feel like this could be useful in many other situations as well.

I saw some useful methods in the testing module of Play, but I failed to use them in a normal environment. And I also don't like the idea of referencing the test module for anything else than testing.

Unfortunately, I am not very good at Scala, but I don't mind having the solution in Scala, as long as I only need to call some method and get the expected result.

Cheers,

Dusan